# Fill missing date-time values in output vector

Tags: r, time-series, unique, missing-data

I performed a unique extraction on my date-time values for extracting unique seconds in my time-series data.

```
unique_seconds <- unlist(unique(all_secondsDayData))
```

I have missing values in my output as follows:

(see "2015-12-03 09:51:26")

```
[1116] "2015-12-03 09:51:24" "2015-12-03 09:51:25" "2015-12-03 09:51:27" "2015-12-03 09:51:28" "2015-12-03 09:51:29"
```

How do I fill my vector with these missing values? 
Do not worry about date because it is one day's data. The issue is filling the vector with missing seconds values.

Comment: `seq(strptime("2015-12-03 09:51:24", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), strptime("2015-12-03 09:51:27", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), by=1)` for example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just want a regular time sequence by 1 second. You may try using `seq.POSIXt`:

```
x <- c("2015-12-03 09:51:24", "2015-12-03 09:51:25", "2015-12-03 09:51:27",
       "2015-12-03 09:51:28", "2015-12-03 09:51:29")

x <- strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

RANGE <- range(x)
seq.POSIXt(RANGE[1], RANGE[2], by = 1)

#[1] "2015-12-03 09:51:24 GMT" "2015-12-03 09:51:25 GMT"
#[3] "2015-12-03 09:51:26 GMT" "2015-12-03 09:51:27 GMT"
#[5] "2015-12-03 09:51:28 GMT" "2015-12-03 09:51:29 GMT"
```

You can read `?seq.POSIXt` for specification of `by`. If it is given as a single number, it is interpreted as "second".