# Inconsistant date in time series

Tags: r, time-series, moving-average, autoregressive-models

I am trying to predict day-to-day number of customers coming into store by using ARIMA model.

I am currently using R to build this model.  However, the data I have is inconsistent. Attached picture is an example of my problem.

For this example, I have 4 customers coming into store in 3/14 and 3 customers in 3/13, 0 customer in 3/12,3/11.  Since I want to predict number of customers coming into store, I will group the data by date.  If I group by date, I will have to inset 0 customers for 3/12, 3/11 because they are not in my database.  Problem is: 1. I am not sure how to how to automatically insert missing date in R. 2. Will that impact the accuracy of my model? 3. In this case, would I get better result to predict week by week instead of day by day?  Thanks

[image]

Anyone know what should I do?  Can I still make prediction on day-to-day base?  Is there any way I could fix this in R?

Comment: ?`na.approx` from package `zoo`

Comment: On the other hand, you seem to have multiple entries for the 14th.  From what I see, you have 4 customers on the 10th, 0 on the 11th, 0 on the 12th, 3 on the 13th, and 4 on the 14th.

Comment: Use `Date` class objects, not just strings. You can use `seq.Date` to get a complete list of days from your min day to your max date, then `merge` to make sure you have 1 row per day. Examples (possible dupes?) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29152654/903061) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39525750/903061)